# Pressure energy in water

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure

If a fluid flowing or rotating  with a certain velocity is stopped, there is an increase in the stagnation pressure or pressure head. So if we spin water in a bucket very quickly and suddenly stop it or obstruct its way, does the pressure head increase in this case? 
If yes, how can we verify?

Answer (score 0):

The question is same as of stopping a chain moving. In chain beads as well as fluid particles the interaction is same. If we stop the moving fluid as shown in figure. Then pressure decreases at front while pressure increases at back. This pressure difference initiates a new force. To keep the the plate in equilibrium we need to exert a force. Thus pressure head increases. That's how we verify.
[image]